# StreamingFileSink configure file name forRowFormat

Tags: apache-flink

I need to configure file names for files created by StreamingFileSink.
I use `ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord` to create parquet files.
Discovered that i cant use `.withOutputFileConfig()` when i use `.forBulkFormat()` (which is available when use `.forRowFormat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working with Flink 1.11